# Error creating bean with name 'bookController'

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jpa

Estou começando aprender Spring e estou recebendo esse erro, já fiz diversas pesquisas na internet porém até o momento não entendi o que está causando o problema:
`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookController' defined in file [C:\bookstroremanager\bookStoreManager\target\classes\com\denilsonf\bookstoremaneger\controller\BookController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookService' defined in file [C:\bookstroremanager\bookStoreManager\target\classes\com\denilsonf\bookstoremaneger\service\BookService.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.denilsonf.bookstoremaneger.service.BookService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

Classe BookController :

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.denilsonf.bookstoremaneger.dto.BookDTO;
import com.denilsonf.bookstoremaneger.dto.MessageResponseDTO;
import com.denilsonf.bookstoremaneger.service.BookService;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/books")
public class BookController {
    
    private BookService bookService;

    @Autowired
    public BookController(BookService bookService){
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public MessageResponseDTO create(@RequestBody @Valid BookDTO bookDTO){
        return bookService.create(bookDTO);
    }
}
```

Classe BookService:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.denilsonf.bookstoremaneger.dto.BookDTO;
import com.denilsonf.bookstoremaneger.dto.MessageResponseDTO;
import com.denilsonf.bookstoremaneger.entity.Book;
import com.denilsonf.bookstoremaneger.mapper.BookMapper;
import com.denilsonf.bookstoremaneger.repository.BookRepository;

@Service
public class BookService {
    
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    private final BookMapper bookMapper = BookMapper.INSTANCE;

    @Autowired
    public BookService(BookRepository bookRepository){
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    public MessageResponseDTO create(BookDTO bookDTO){
        Book bookToSave = bookMapper.toModel(bookDTO);
        Book savedBook = bookRepository.save(bookToSave);
        return MessageResponseDTO.builder()
                .message("Book created with ID " + savedBook.getId())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Classe BookMapper:

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

import com.denilsonf.bookstoremaneger.dto.BookDTO;
import com.denilsonf.bookstoremaneger.entity.Book;

@Mapper
public interface BookMapper {

    BookMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(BookMapper.class);
    
    Book toModel(BookDTO bookDTO);

    BookDTO toDTO(Book book);
}
```

Comment: Amigo, é difícil indicar onde está o erro no teu projeto Spring, pois para reproduzi-lo, seria necessário ter acesso à boa parte das classes. Minha recomendação é - observa a mensagem de erro inteira (todo o stacktrace) que ela vai indicar qual beam não foi inicializado corretamente, e então tu vais resolvendo os problemas.

Comment: Opa, dei uma olhada no código que estou usando como referencia para o meu e esta praticamente igual, vou deixar aqui o repositório no GitHub https://github.com/DenilsonSilvaMonteiroFilho/bookStoreManager, desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Remove esses contrutores, as anotaçoes do spring boot definem automaticamente Beans. Seu problema está aí.

Comment: Implementei todas as resoluções que foram recomendadas, após perceber que não estava resolvendo o problema e em alguns casos gerando um erro de Nullpoint. Fui rever o meu pom.xml e percebi que estava faltando a configuração de build do mapstrut. Após realizar essa correção o código rodou normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Teria de ver o código todo para ter certeza, mas me parece um erro de mapeamento que não está permitindo que o Spring encontre a classe `bookService`.

Tente escanea-las utilizando o `@ComponentScan` na sua classe principal:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"package.controller", "package.service", "package.dao"})
public class YourApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Ou refatore seu código para que a sua classe principal fique acima dos outros pacotes e classes. Algo assim:

```
yourApp
     |_src
        |_main
             |_java
                 |_package.controller  
                 |_package.dao  
                 |_package.service  
                 |_YourApplication.java
```

Comment: Opa, tentei utilizar o @ComponentScan da maneira que você recomendou e de outras formas, dessa maneira que foi recomendada o erro que apresentava não se fez presente, porem quando se tenta fazer o Post ele apresenta "Not Found". Vou deixar aqui o repositório no GitHub: https://github.com/DenilsonSilvaMonteiroFilho/bookStoreManager , desde já agradeço a ajuda :)

Answer (score 0):

O `@Autowired` está no lugar errado.

Ele serve para dizer que um componente deve ser instanciado pelo mecanismo de injeção de dependências e portanto deve ser colocado sobre a declaração de componente que uma classe depende e não sobre um construtor.

Em outras palavras, em vez de colocar no construtor de `BookService`, coloque nessa linha de `BookController`:

```
@Autowired
private BookService bookService;
```

Isso é evidenciado pela mensagem de erro *"Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0"*, que, traduzida, fica:

> Dependência não-satisfeita expressada através do parâmetro 0 do construtor

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma olhada neste artigo: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-beancreationexception

Rodei seu código aqui testando algumas possibilidades do link acima, talvez o que esteja faltando seja um método Setter para o bean `bookMapper` na classe `BookService`.

Troque isso:

```
private final BookMapper bookMapper = BookMapper.INSTANCE;
```

Por isto:

```
private BookMapper bookMapper;

public void setBookMapper(final BookMapper bookMapper){
    this.bookMapper = bookMapper;
}
```